# How to create an \mbox with more than one lines?

Tags: boxes, forms

I am using LaTeX to compose homework for my students. I use `\CheckBox` for multichoice test and `\mbox` for text typing. In the outcome PDF file the `\mbox` environment allows typing in 1 line even though the width of the box is big enough (please see the attached screenshot). Can I fix that in LaTeX such that in the outcome PDF file one can fill out more then one lines?
[image]

Can I edit the `CheckBox` environment; for example, change the default color of its red border lines to blue, select another letter font and size. Lastly, how can I vertically center the `\mbox` squares with the text?

Here is a code example I use:

```
\documentclass[1pt]{article}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Choose the correct answer:

\vspace{1em}

\def\LayoutCheckField#1#2{#2 #1}
\noindent
\begin{Form}
    \CheckBox[height=4mm,width=4mm]{A}\\[1em]
    \CheckBox[height=4mm,width=4mm]{B}\\[1em]
    \CheckBox[height=4mm,width=4mm]{C}
\end{Form}

\vspace{2em}

\noindent
\lipsum[1]

\vspace{1em}

\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{#2}
\begin{Form}
\def\DefaultHeightofText{70pt}
\noindent
\mbox{\strut\TextField[width=\textwidth,height=2.5cm]{name13}}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I suggest you ask one question at a time, as this is the preferred style on this site. As for the box: `\TextField[width=\textwidth,height=2.5cm,multiline]{name13}` would make it multi-line. What do you mean with "vertically center the `\mbox` squares with the text"?

Comment: Have a look at chapter 7 of the [`hyperref` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.pdf). You will find a lot of options there that may be helpful.

Comment: By the way, I hope that all your students use Acrobat Reader to do their homework! Forms are one of those parts of PDFs where the various PDF viewers differ vastly in terms of what they display and how they let the user interact with the different elements.

Comment: You could use `\parbox[c]{<width>}{<text>}` instead of `\mbox{<text>}` to get boxes in which the text is linebreakable.

Comment: `multiline` works. Thank you @JasperHabicht. Hyperref manual is indeed helpful--thanks. Regarding the "vertically center the `\mbox` squares with the text", I meant to align the `\mbox` and the text vertically in the center.

Comment: Thanks for the PDF tip. As far as I know, there were no issues with the PDF format other than the `multiline` typing.